# How do I exclude directories from an IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I know why the following code does not work when the "excl" list has more than one string. It's because as each string is evaluated in the lambda it now includes whatever was excluded in the previous iteration of "x." My question is, how do I get it to properly exclude multiple items in the final result?

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.10\e$");

var excl = new List<string>();
excl.Add("Temp");
excl.Add("VSS");

var dirs = from d in di.GetDirectories()
           where (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System
           select d;                       

dirs = excl
       .SelectMany(x => from d in dirs
       where !d.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(x.ToLowerInvariant())
       select d)
       .Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.10\e$");
var dirs = di.EnumerateDirectories()
             .Where(d=> !excl.Any(e=>d.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(e)));
```

I would think about your exclusion criteria though - do you want to exclude every directory that *contains* your exclusion string or just directories whose names *match* a exclusion item?

Also to make this faster you can create a `HashSet<string>` from your exclusion list and use that.

Comment: Looks like Chris Shain beat you by a minute. I was looking into the Intersect<> documentation and was reading up on hashcodes, but I knew there would be a one line solution for this problem. This code is just for a partial match of a directory path, not an exact match.

Comment: You're right, I was going by his showing up first. This was my first question on here, didn't realize it shows the answers newest to oldest, even though they're clearly numbered! I'll switch answers.

Answer (score 3):

What it seems like you want to do is this (nested iteration):

```
dirs = dirs.Where(d => !excl.Any(x => d.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(x.ToLowerInvariant())))
   .Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry I gave you the answer but didn't realize you came in a minute late.

Comment: No sweat- neither @BrokenGlass or I are going to worry too much over 15 rep points :-)